# Azure mobile service for android query table

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using azure sdk for android and follow the tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-android-get-started-data/.
When I'm trying to connect and insert data to mobile service table all is ok, but when I query the table in activity my app gets stuck, though there are only several entries in the table and execute method successfully returns Future.

public static MobileServiceClient mClient;

```
public static void connect(Context context) {
    try {
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient(storageLink, key, context);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("AzureService.connect", "Storage access failed" + storageLink);
    }
}

public static InstallationData get(final String deviceId) {
    MobileServiceTable<InstallationData> table= mClient.getTable(InstallationData.class);
    final MobileServiceList<InstallationData> result;
    try {
        result = table.where().field("deviceid").eq(deviceId).execute().get();
        for (InstallationData item : result) {
           return item;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void store(final InstallationData item) {
    mClient.getTable(InstallationData.class).insert(item, new TableOperationCallback<InstallationData>() {
        public void onCompleted(InstallationData entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if (exception == null) {
                Log.d("AzureService.store()", "Data about " + item.getDeviceid() + "" + "is successfully updated");
            } else {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("AzureService.store()", "Data about " + item.getDeviceid() + "" + "is failed to update");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: plzz.....post your full snippet of your code...and elaborate... what is the purpose of this code...whether u r trying to populate a list view ????

Comment: what error are u getting??